# Есть ли такой плагин, который при скролле проверяет какая секция на экране и если надо менять url в share button?

Tags: javascript

при скролле проверять какая секция на экране и если надо менять url кнопок share button, в каждой секции свои ссылки, кто то знает подходящий плагин?
плагин который будет проверять ссылку секции и вставлять ее в кнопку, по которой можно будет поделиться в соц сетях

Comment: Плагин к чему именно?

Comment: плагин который будет проверять ссылку секции и вставлять ее в кнопку, по которой можно будет поделиться в соц сетях

Comment: Нет таких плагинов готовых.